# Why is the MKMapView's userLocation property rubbish ... for a while?

Tags: iphone, location, mapkit

I have a Map View defined in IB and it is set to show the user location.

In my app, in *-viewDidAppear*, I query self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate and it comes back with insane values such as:

*latitude*: 4.8194501961644877e-49
*longitude*: 2.2993313035571993e-59

However, the next time *-viewDidAppear* is called (after I've simply moved to another tabbed view and then back to this one) the *userLocation* property holds exactly the correct values for my current location.

It seems that at the time of my initial call, the *userLocation* property has not been initialised but despite having read Apple's documentation I can't see any caveats where it says that this property is only valid after doing xxx.

Is there something that has to happen before *userLocation* is valid to use or should I just use *CLLocationManager* and ask it instead?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Sadly, Thomas' suggestion didn't help. What I have since discovered is:

If *showsUserLocation* is NO, then *userLocation* is never set correctly and *-MapView:didUpdateUserLocation:* is never called, consequently I never ever get a sensible location value.

So, to get the user's location I have to set *showsUserLocation* to YES, however that then means that after all my annotations have been added to the view (without including the user's location) I then calculate the required span to encompass them all and display them all at the right zoom level. After I do that though, the view jumps sideways as the Map View then automatically displays the user's location as the blue blob! As it was never included in the annotations to work out the zoom level I can't incorporate it into my calculations. Aaargh!

Note that when *showsUserLocation* is YES, then *-MapView:didUpdateUserLocation:* is called, but only after I've calculated all the coordinates of my annotations, not before!

Comment: *Note that when showsUserLocation is YES, then -MapView:didUpdateUserLocation: is called, but only after I've calculated all the coordinates of my annotations, not before!* well then, why don't you calculate the coordinates of your annotations when this first gets called?! lol... calculate it IN this method. :p

Comment: Hi Thomas - indeed! I was looking at the code again last night and putting NSLog statement around and that was the conclusion I came to as well! I'll report back soon. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming it hasn't finished finding the user location - it has to work this out and it may take a while.

Instead of using it in `viewDidLoad` use THIS delegate method:

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)myMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation;`

You will need to set your mapview delegate to self. :)

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work Thomas - please see my extra discoveries added above.

Comment: Calculate and update your map region in the `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` method -- that way you can include all your annotations and the user's location.  Also, note that that delegate method will continue to be called as the phone updates its GPS coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I found that it's repeatedly called even when my iPod is stationary on my desk!

Answer (score 1):

Same is often true of Core Location. You'll get the last location lingering it its buffer, sometimes, or a super-broad throw-the-dart-at-the-map kind of location...

Best bet is to check the `.horizontalAccuracy` property of the location object and toss any that are too vague. It's good practice to just chuck the first one too.

Answer (score 0):

for didUpdateUserLocation to be called you have to have...
mapView.showsUserLocation = TRUE;