# Showing region around current location in MKMapKit View

Tags: mkmapview

I have this code in ViewDidLoad that should show the region around current location of user but it is now working

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        costaCoffeeMapView.delegate = self;

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.2;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = costaCoffeeMapView.userLocation.coordinate;

    region.center=location;
    region.span=span;

    [costaCoffeeMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [costaCoffeeMapView regionThatFits:region];

}
```

I am trying to get the current user location from the MKMapView object "costaCoffeeMapView" as in the Attribute Inspector, "Show User Location" is checked for the MKMapView.

Instead of showing the region of current location, that is, London, UK. It shows a region somewhere in the south atlantic ocean. I think exactly at the (0.2,0.2) coordinates.

What is wrong? please help

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times.  The user location isn't always ready immediately in viewDidLoad.  You have to use the didUpdateUserLocation delegate method.  Search for it.  One example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606539/why-is-the-mkmapviews-userlocation-property-rubbish-for-a-while